# Find spatially identical records in Mapinfo

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

Is there a tool/mbx similar to the Arc INFO "[Find Identical](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000054000000)" to find records which have exactly the same shape?

Answer (score 1):

Search for "duplicates" here:
http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l?hl=en

The question has been asked many times.

Comment: Thanks...the issue with this is they all DELETE records. I should have highlighted that I just want to mark them/select them as I need to then manually check and incorporate all the updated attributes into a single record and then delete the others.

Comment: There's a discussion on only finding (not deleting) them here http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/browse_thread/thread/8f254fe8dbe57ded/15c25e11226d3c90?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=%22How+to+find+duplicate+polylines%22#15c25e11226d3c90 Apparently this should do what you need - I haven't tried it though and description is amusingly badly written http://www.mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=8&sobi2Id=281&Itemid=53